# How to animate an Android View only once on startup?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity, view

I am currently working on a very simple UI for my Android App. My goal is to animate some (I don't know how many yet) buttons on startup and NEVER AGAIN.

So following the official docs, reading java doc and searching on stackoverflow aswell, I finally got it work. Here's what I do with a single test view.

- Set the View and the Animation in the OnCreate() method.

```java
private TextView test_text;
private Animation test_anim;
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ...

   test_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
   test_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.test_animation);
}
```

- Start the Animation in the OnWindowFocusChanged() method.

```java
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     test_text.startAnimation(test_anim);
}
```

This procedure works, the animation is executed when the activity starts, the only problem is that the onWindowFocusChanged() method is called everytime the activity changes status. So the text animates when the app is resumed, when the layout rotates and stuff like that.

So, repeating: My goal is to animate the text only ONCE when the app boots up and then stop forever.

If it helps, I already tried to put the Animation start in other methods like onStart() or onResume(), but the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add a boolean variable with initial value true and after first time you can change its value to false and inside onfocus you can add another condition

```
If(boolean){do the animation;
boolean=false;}
```

this will do want you want but if you want the animation to be once during the application life cycle you can use shared prefs or simply add a static Boolean variable in application class

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePreferences, to check a boolean value. If is true or not exists means is first launch or you can animate app in onWindowFOcusChange() method. Set it to false to never aniamte again.

```
////////////////////////////
/// CONSTANTS
////////////////////////////

private static final String PREF_NAME = "pref_name";
public static final String IS_STARTUP = "is_startup";

////////////////////////////
/// FIELDS
////////////////////////////

private SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.getBoolean(IS_START_UP, true)) {
            test_text.startAnimation(test_anim);
            settings.edit().putBoolean(IS_START_UP, false).commit();
        }
 }
```

In case you want to aniamte again when app starts next time, you can set the pref IS_START_UP to true when exit the application.

```
if (!settings.getBoolean(IS_START_UP, false)) {
    settings.edit().putBoolean(IS_START_UP, true).commit();
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it. The shared prefs work in every situation except when I rotate the screen. In that case the animation repeats again. It's like every time you rotate the screen, the activity restarts from the beginning. Any idea how to solve this? Maybe it's something I don't know about the screen rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference to store a boolean variable & make it to true immediately after first animation & check this each time before animation starts.

```
if(!isAnimatedAlready){
animate();
setIsAnimated(true);
}else{}
```